# how to extend method in typescript

Tags: typescript

I saw an article about extension method in typescript (https://medium.com/my-coding-life/extension-method-in-typescript-66d801488589)  and try to implement my own extension method in a ts file.

**alias.ts**:

```
interface Array<T> {
  remove(item: any): void,
  draw(): any
};

Array.prototype.remove = function (item) {
  let id = this.indexOf(item);
  id !== false && this.splice(id, 1);
};

Array.prototype.draw = function () {
  return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)];
};
```

everything looks fine so far, However, it gives me errors after I imported momentJs. Anyone know what the problem is?

[image]

Comment: Could you give us the version of your TypeScript compiler?

Comment: it is version 3.6.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```js
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        remove(item: any): void,
        draw(): any
    }
}

Array.prototype.remove = function (item) {
    let id = this.indexOf(item);
    id !== false && this.splice(id, 1);
};

Array.prototype.draw = function () {
    return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)];
};
```

Hope it helps

Comment: As a side note, I would also give the the type `T` to the `item` parameter of `remove` and `draw` return type, to have a stronger type-checking: `remove(item: T): void` and `draw(): T`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I'm clear now after checking the doc about declare global